# How do I return objects from an API call as an Organized List instead of a run-on sentence?

Tags: list, join

I am currently calling an API to return a list of streaming platforms. The API works, and returns objects as intended.

example of a returned call:
"Netflix, Stan, Starz, Viaplay, Kinopoisk, Starz Play Amazon Channel, Crave Starz, Be TV Go, Yelo Play, Movistar Play, HBO Max, HBO Go, NOW, Wink, KPN, SkyShowtime, Lionsgate Plus, Starz Amazon Channel"

On my displayed HTML page I'd like to break these up as a list, instead of just being separated by commas using the .join method (the only method I've thus far learned).

How can I go about doing this?

Here is the chunk of my code that calls the API and joins the results:

```
    const providers = Object.values(providerMap).join(", ");
```

What can I used instead of .join to make an organized list instead?
(Also, is it possible to sort the list as it is returned, say alphabetically or by price?)

Answer (score 0):

`Object.values(providerMap)` itself should give you an array. If you want this array to be sorted alphabetically you can use `Object.values(providerMap).sort()`